# Node-Red TypeError

Tags: raspbian, node.js

Installed Node-red on Pi 2 (not much experience on linux btw). 
I can easily start node-red with node red.js and see it is running.

But when opening the browser to start node-red editor at pi IP  my case > http://192.168.1.50:1880 it fires an error and i lost connection to server on the browser.

also tried with https://192.168.1.50:1880 but still getting the error.
Anyone same experience ?

using raspian

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/node-red $ node red.js


Welcome to Node-RED
===================

18 Jun 09:16:53 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.10.7.git
18 Jun 09:16:53 - [info] Node.js  version: v0.12.1
18 Jun 09:16:53 - [info] Loading palette nodes
18 Jun 09:17:01 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
18 Jun 09:17:01 - [warn] Failed to register 3 node types
18 Jun 09:17:01 - [warn] Run with -v for details
18 Jun 09:17:01 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
18 Jun 09:17:01 - [info] Settings file  : ./settings
18 Jun 09:17:01 - [info] User Directory : /home/pi/.node-red
18 Jun 09:17:01 - [info] Flows file     : /home/pi/.node-red/flows_raspberrypi.json
18 Jun 09:17:01 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
18 Jun 09:17:01 - [info] Creating new flows file
18 Jun 09:17:01 - [info] Starting flows
18 Jun 09:17:01 - [info] Started flows


18 Jun 12:56:41 - [red] Uncaught Exception:
18 Jun 12:56:41 - TypeError: argument entity must be string, Buffer, or fs.Stats
    at etag (/home/pi/node-red/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/node_modules/etag/index.js:55:11)
    at SendStream.setHeader (/home/pi/node-red/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:724:15)
    at SendStream.send (/home/pi/node-red/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:500:8)
    at onstat (/home/pi/node-red/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:585:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:99:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is already open issue in Node red community.
Open state: https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/565

Specific to the error is in closed state.
https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/656